# Is there an iPhone podcatcher?

Tags: iphone, itunes, software-recommendation, podcasts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What apps are available for subscribing to podcasts directly on the iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/what-apps-are-available-for-subscribing-to-podcasts-directly-on-the-iphone)

I was glad to see that you can download podcasts directly from the iTunes app on the iPhone, rather than having to keep the iTunes app open to play them, but there's a 20 MB cap on downloads.

I'm looking for a way to subscribe to and automatically download new podcasts over 3G. Is there an app that can do this?