# subscribe to a podcast on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What apps are available for subscribing to podcasts directly on the iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/what-apps-are-available-for-subscribing-to-podcasts-directly-on-the-iphone)

Does anyone have a clever hack to subscribe to podcasts on iOS? The important characteristics are. Obviously one can use iTunes and sync, or manually download directly from iOS. I'm looking for something that automatically downloads podcasts as they become available (when on wifi) and doesn't require me to plug in to a computer.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you might have.