# iPad podcasts without a PC

Tags: ipad, itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What apps are available for subscribing to podcasts directly on the iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/what-apps-are-available-for-subscribing-to-podcasts-directly-on-the-iphone)

What is the de facto standard way of subscribing to podcasts on iPad without using iTunes on a PC?  iTunes on iPad lets one download podcast episodes listed in the iTMS but not subscribe to them.

This could be a cloud based podcast aggregator or an iPad app.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/what-apps-are-available-for-subscribing-to-podcasts-directly-on-the-iphone/8173#8173) for an app called [Podcaster](http://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/podcaster-formerly-rss-player/id377195245?mt=8)