# How to listen to these downloaded BBC radio shows with Catalina?

Tags: ios, itunes, software-recommendation, books, podcasts

For years I have been downloading radio shows from the BBC, tagging them as 'podcasts' and putting them into iTunes. With the Catalina update these files no longer seem to be listenable!

The Podcasts app doesn't see them as it only seems to see things that are actual podcasts on the Apple Store.

The Music app won't import them (perhaps because of their 'podcast' meta data?)

The Books app will import them but see the 'shows' as chapters in one huge book - also sorting them alphabetically by the 'episode name' which doesn't have the date - making it impossible to listen to them in order or mark them as 'listened'.

What can I do to be able to listen to these files and sync them in a manageable way to my iPhone?

Is there a 3rd party app that will do this for me? I'd prefer to stay with apple native apps, but at this point I'm desperate!

**Update**: bizarrely enough, from the new Finder view of an iPhone all my old podcasts are still there and can be synced. So the data IS inside iTunes, but hidden from any view that I can find. This does not in any way help me as I can't seem to add new shows and it has lost all record of the 'listened' field that iTunes had before, so it thinks all shows are new again.

Comment: Most video players can play audio too, can you try VLC etc ?https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366075/how-to-add-podcasts-manually-to-the-new-podcasts-app-on-macos-catalina This just reiterates what you wrote.

Comment: @ankii thanks but this does not address how to sync them to my iphone (and mark them as listened etc).

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/what-apps-are-available-for-subscribing-to-podcasts-directly-on-the-iphone

Comment: The answers on that question are almost a decade old and also don't address the situation I am referring to. Those are actual podcasts. Mine are radio shows that I am downloading and had been marking as type 'podcast' in iTunes.